# /sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Tags: ubuntu

When I run ldconfig on my Ubuntu box, I get the warning:

/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

This is not causing any problems yet AFAIK, but I want to 'fix' it, incase it comes back to bite me later on. Does anyone know why I am getting this message - and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

The other answers didn't work for me, I fixed with below commands

```bash
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libc-bin
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and I believe this is intended to be a directory location for Multiarch support. See file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf`.

The way I got the error to go away was to create the directory, as it did not exist in my machine.  I ran this as root:

```
mkdir /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 3):

A similar error occurred now on Debian 11 under WSL2. The fix was to create the directory in /usr/local/lib, as mentioned by Miguel Gualdron (sorry, can't comment, and maybe it's better to have this as info for Debian too). The full error message is below.

```
Setting up libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u2) ...
Aborted (core dumped)
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/usr/lib/wsl/lib:
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Just to clarify - You created the folder /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to get this error 134 to go away? - im having the same issue and Im not having any luck

Comment: @Syllogism Yes, the full path is /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. The directory is empty. You can see the initial error and get it from there :: ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

have the same error in wsl2 debian,fix it by modify the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf`
just leave one row :
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions have had helped me. The only thing that did was simple

```
sudo apt install libc-bin
```