# Trying to update libc-bin error state 134 - cant sudo install net-tools

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Cannot get net-tools to install on Linux because of this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 316 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/633 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3802 kB of additional disk space will be used.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Selecting previously unselected package libc-bin.
(Reading database ... 57438 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc-bin_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Setting up libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Aborted (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib32' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
        libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/usr/lib/wsl/lib:
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I Tried purging and reinstalling with no success
`sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libc-bin`
`sudo apt-get install libc-bin`

Fairly new to Linux so I would love to have someone tell me what I can do to fix this.

Not sure where to look next.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/x86\_64-linux-gnu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930543/sbin-ldconfig-real-cant-stat-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu)

Comment: @DanielFarrell I tried to follow the instructions here but I am getting the same error code 134

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried many commands but always get the error `dpkg: error processing package libc-bin` like you.
The only method that worked for me is below.

Try to install net-tools after these commands.

```bash
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libc-bin
```

Comment: This was the most helpful in getting unstuck from where I was - alot of my issues came from the wonky-ness of WSL. thank you @Sunghoon Cho